# How to define decimal data type for fixtures in Cakephp2.x?

Tags: php, testing, cakephp, fixtures, cakephp-2.x

I am creating a fixture for testing in cakephp2.x. I want to define the field type as a decimal, which is straightforward. However, I want to define it specifically with `DECIMAL(6,4)`, but cannot figure out how to set the digits.

I can't find it in the cookbook either: https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/testing.html

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify both in the column definitions `length` option, like so:

```php
public $fields = array(
    'column_name' => array(
        'type' => 'decimal',
        'length' => '6,4',
        'null' => false,
    ),
    // ...
);
```

Comment: thanks so much!! that worked. I'm wondering, how did you find that out? I couldn't find it anywhere in the cookbook

Comment: @ymg I remembered it from years ago, and I had a quick look at the tests to confirm: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.24/lib/Cake/Test/Fixture/DatatypeFixture.php#L34**.